# Yii2 - Initialise a model with array value

Tags: php, arrays, yii, yii2

How to create a model which is have a default value from another array.

I mean, if I have an array like this :

```
[
0 => [
    'remarks' => 'ACETONE - '
    'material' => '70.00'
]
1 => [
    'remarks' => 'Leak Test 1 Bar'
    'material' => '13.50'
]
2 => [
    'remarks' => 'Foot Valve Incapsulated O-Ring 1 pcs - Replace'
    'material' => '6.70'
]
3 => [
    'remarks' => 'Seal Teflon 3\" Bottom Valve - Replace'
    'material' => '10.50'
]
4 => [
    'remarks' => 'Gasket Carton Bottom Valve 4 Hole 2 pcs - Replace'
    'material' => '14.60'
]
]
```

You know, The model just store one default value like this :

```
$modelJobOrderDetails =[new JobOrderDetail([
                'remarks' => ?? get from array above
                'material' => ?? get from array above
            ])] ;
```

How about to store those array into this model ?
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have

```
 $myArray =    [
      0 => [
          'remarks' => 'ACETONE - '
          'material' => '70.00'
      ]
      1 => [
          'remarks' => 'Leak Test 1 Bar'
          'material' => '13.50'
      ]
      2 => [
          'remarks' => 'Foot Valve Incapsulated O-Ring 1 pcs - Replace'
          'material' => '6.70'
      ]
      3 => [
          'remarks' => 'Seal Teflon 3\" Bottom Valve - Replace'
          'material' => '10.50'
      ]
      4 => [
          'remarks' => 'Gasket Carton Bottom Valve 4 Hole 2 pcs - Replace'
          'material' => '14.60'
      ]
    ];
```

you could iterate over your array an poplulatin using model-attributes

```
  foreach($mymodel as $key = $value)        {
      $models[$key] = new JobOrderDetail();
      $models[$key]->attributes = $value;

  }
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#massive-assignment

Answer (score 6):

read this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail

```
$model = new JobOrderDetail();
$model->load($arrayData, ''); // '' = formname or empty string
```

this way, you make sure only the (safe) attributes you want are loaded. $arrayData is an array of key/value pairs for ONE model. you have to iterate yourself.

Comment: Coming from the future, your solution saved me a lot of time. Thank you, kind stranger!